# onSurfaceTextureDestroyed is not called even when activity is destroyed

Tags: android, android-textureview

I have a Texture View , For which i have set `setSurfaceTextureListener` . I use this texture view to show live camera feed in my app. I am handling **BACK KEY** in app explicitly . **On BACK KEY** press i call " `finish()` " method to destroy my activity . The " `onDestroy` "  Method of the activity gets called .

But the " `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` " method which i have set on my texture View does not get called . I am not sure if it's OK to link this problem with android version But , Interestingly " `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` " gets called when i use my app on **KITKAT** . Its giving problem on Jelly Beans.

Also As i check , When i press HOME Key :-
On **jelly bean**`onPause` and `onStop` gets called .
But On **KITKAT** onPause and `onStop` and `onDestroy` all three gets called.

I want to know why " `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` " is not called even when activity's " `onDestroy` " is called .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the issue . I was setting the setSurfaceTextureListener to null on activity Ondestroy . Thats why it was not being called.